# eclipse android AVD virtual diver Nexus 6 no longer exists as a driver

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, android-virtual-device

Actually, I'm using an AVD for my Android APP. Tested for many time.     But, it cannot be launched suddenly.                                         And shows it need repair. And `error: Google Nexus 6 no longer exists as a diver`, I check the Path Nexus_6_API_21 is here. How can I do?

I cannot run other driver too, as they keep loading and loading for a time and shows nothing....
Also, I cannot create other a new drive by Nexus 6 too... it disappeared.
(it show `HAX is running... fast... mode` when i run Nexus 6 before.

And other driver not show this)<-is it a reason of running time?

Comment: Open SDK manager and see if the Android L drivers are installed.

Comment: where is it as I cannot see "Android L driver" in the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: I find the Android 5.0.1(API 21) only "Simple for SDK" and "EABI v7a System Image" not installed, all others installed.

Comment: Install everything under it!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have that option in your **AVD** you can create a new definition for the device.

Please follow [this link Managing AVDs with AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html).

Mainly the section [CREATING AN AVD](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html#createavd)

You can see there is a **Creating a device definition** follow that step and you will be able to create your own nexus-6 device.

Here is the reference image to create a new defination of your avd

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: i cant found the option "Nexus 6" in this page, but i found two Nexus 7, one is "Nexus 7" another is "Nexus 7(2012)".